# $http.get doesn't have all headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to download a file from my web-api controller. I succeded until I wanted to get the custom header of the response.

web-api controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("vorlage")]
[ResponseType(typeof(object))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(object))]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadVorlage()
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Properties.Resources.Vorlage_Batch);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "original name.xlsx";
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    result.Headers.Add("X-Filename", "original name.xlsx");
    return result;
}
```

angularjs code

```
function DownloadVorlage($scope, $http, WebApiBaseUri) {
    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: WebApiBaseUri + 'batchmode/vorlage',
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    };
    $http(request).then(function (response) {
        var headers = response.headers();
        var filename = headers['X-Filename'] || 'replacement name.xlsx';
        var contentType = headers['content-type'] || 'application/octet-stream';
        download(response.data, filename, contentType);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

The content is in the right type and it is possible to save the file.
When I test the API with postman I got all headerinformation that I need.
But all header information I go are:

```
cache-control: "no-cache"
content-type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
expires: "-1"
pragma: "no-cache"
```

I'm missing the "X-Filename" information and have no clue how to get it.